# How to retrieve the size of all my Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is there a quick way to retrieve all the sizes of each of my Google Cloud Storage bucket?

We do not see the size in the UI.
I have to do:

```
gsutil du -s -h gs://xxxx
```

for each bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCS does not provide this as a feature. What you're doing is likely the fastest way.

You could write a program to dynamically track the size of a bucket by watching change notifications, or you could use Cloud Storage's [daily storage logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs) to get regular reports on it, but there's no instant way to see the current size.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and found you can run the following command to find the size of all the buckets within your project.
Just replace project-id with your own.

```
gsutil -o GSUtil:default_project_id=project-id du -shc
```