# Google cloud storage directory size

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to find out how to calculate the size of a directory inside a google-cloud-storage bucket.

I've found two ways so far:

- Using `gsutils` (which I can't really, because it won't be available in the machine I need to do this from)
- Using the `getMetadata` method from the `nodejs` library.

The problem is that the `getMetatada` method only works on files, and not directories (or prefixes as they're called).

I could list all the files and ask them all for their size but `getMetadata` doesn't allow for query batching and I would probably be making people angry at @google.

Do you guys know of any way to do that properly in a respectful manner?

Sincerely

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you were able to use `gsutil`, you could use [du](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/du), like this:

`gsutil du -sh YOUR_BUCKET/YOUR_DIRECTORY`

The `-s` flag will give you only the size of the directory, if you remove it you will also see the size of the files inside. The `-h` flag returns the size in a human-readable format (KiB,MiB, etc). If not present, it will display the size in bytes.

But, since you mention you can't do it like that, you will have to use, as mentioned, `getMetadata`.

This simple script will show the size in the console, in bytes, of all of your files in the folder you wish. You can later modify it to add up those sizes.

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
   const projectId = "PROJECT-ID";
   const bucketName = "BUCKET-NAME";
   const storage = Storage({
       projectId: projectId,
   });
  const options = {
    prefix: "FOLDER-IN-BUCKET/"
  }
  storage
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .getFiles(options)
    .then(results => {
        const files = results[0];
        files.forEach(file => {
          storage.
            bucket(bucketName)
            .file(file.name)
            .getMetadata()
            .then(metadata_results => {
                const metadata = metadata_results[0];
                console.log(metadata.size);
                console.log(metadata.name);
          }).catch(metadata_err => {
            console.error(metadata_err);
          });
        });
     }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080);
console.log("Hello World");
```

Don't forget to add the dependency for [Cloud Storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage) in your `package.json`.

You can follow [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43808279/how-to-retrieve-the-size-of-all-my-google-cloud-storage-bucket/43810453#43810453), use daily storage logs, and read said logs from Node

Comment: Thank you @Mangu, this is something I considered indeed but those directories might become quite large and I don't want to start annoying people at google by making a call for each file in a directory.

Comment: Sincerely, I would only worry about the [costs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing) of the calls, nothing more.

Comment: Yup, but also time of run.

And also, I don't control the amount of files that people will upload, so I don't control the cost.

Comment: You can follow [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43810453/3058302), use daily storage logs, and read said logs from Node. Other than that, I don't see another possible option.

Comment: Thanks for the help Mangu :)

Comment: I have included the last option in an edit. If you like it, please accept it, for future reference of the community.